# Parsing sound files

Tags: parsing, audio

while doing my assignment I came across a question that I don't understand. Not sure if this is the place to post this but can anyone explain what is expected of me and how to do this please?

Thank you [image]

Comment: A user can input a category for songs. Depending on what they have selected a different file is used. It allows for a different selection of songs to choose from.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example please?

Comment: What kind of programming language are you using?

Comment: You "just" have to read 3 CSV files, then make some kind of selection in the names read in the files. That has nothing to do with audio!

Comment: I'm using python 3. The assignment is creating a Radio station using a raspberry pi then inputting the sound using parsing of text files and audio given to me by the teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_name="adverts.txt"
file = open(file_name, 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    fSongList = line.split(',')
```

It would be something like this for each.